# Count records for a user for a given timeframe following a date

Tags: sql, postgresql

**So I have the following table:**

| User | Date |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-05 |
| A | 2020-07-01 |
| A | 2020-09-01 |
| A | 2020-12-31 |
| B | 2020-03-01 |
| B | 2020-11-05 |

**But what I want to do is:**

1. Take the minimum (first) date for each user, and then
2. Count the number of records for that user after that minimum (first) date

**Below is an example of what I want to achieve using PostgreSQL:**

| User | min_date | count_of_records_in_6_months |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2020-01-05 | 2 |
| B | 2020-03-01 | 0 |

**What I've tried thus far is below (obviously this is just giving me a total count of each user).**

```
SELECT 
user
,MIN(date) as min_date
,count(*) as count_of_records
FROM myTable
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: You want the count in the 6 months after the minimum date? Or last six months relative to current date?

Comment: I want the count of records for each user **after** their minimum date (as reflected in my example output table)

Comment: 2020-07-10 is more than 6 months after 2020-01-05.  Your question is unclear.

Comment: That was my mistake as a typo ... I corrected to 2020-07-01 (putting it within 6 months from the minimum date of the first user)

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT user,
       COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE date <= min_date + interval '6 month')
FROM (SELECT t.*, MIN(date) OVER (PARTITION BY user) as min_date
      FROM myTable t
     ) t
GROUP BY user;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1d226a07d679b88d2701511f7fcf5dc8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: I see, but will this get me the end table I presented as an example above?

Comment: Gordon ... are you using "t" to reference "myTable"? Also, are you missing a parentheses in the sub-query?

Comment: Also `filter` should exclude the minimum date that was calculated

Comment: The answer supplied doesn't seem to work nor does it give me the end result I am seeking...

Comment: any insight here?

Comment: @Hyder . . . The code does what you seem to specify in the question, which is counting the records in the first 6 months.